# Official insignia for regions?

Tags: pokemon-series

I'm doing some design work on my Pokémon fan-game, and I was just wondering if there was anything at all that could be considered an official flag or other insignia that could be used to identify each of the regions in the Pokémon games?

Comment: Other than the cover art of the different legendaries (and starters in RBY's case), there's no 'official' insignias that I'm aware of. You might have more luck watching the anime - Kanto's series heavily used the 'Pokeball' icon/insignia, whereas Johto's was centred around the 'GS Ball' IIRC. I didn't watch the rest, but certainly each series has been represented by different themes/ideas

Comment: I did a little bit of research, and couldn't find anything like official flags or emblems or the sort. The best I could find were official artwork of the respective regions' map. I'm guessing Nintendo never bothered designing region flags, so you're pretty much free to do whatever.

Answer (score 1):

There are no official insignias, flags, or logos for each region. The closest representation I was able to find was either the badge collections for each region, or map artwork. There are lots of other options for things you can do to uniquely represent each region, however, including referring to them by name, by their Kanji, or by League Trophies (though Hoenn and Sinoh are very similar, and Kalos doesn't have one yet). There are also a number of different fan created variations on what flags might look like all over the web, including some inspired by the real life regions the maps are from, which may work as well.